# help proving this cannot be a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Im just not really sure how to go about this.  I'm assuming it involves cases where you take m and n to be x mod some number.
given integers $m$ and $n$.  show that $3^m+3^n+1$ cannot be a perfect square.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Observe that any perfect square must be congruent to $0, 1$, or
$4$ modulo $8$

**Added:**

First noticing that $3^2\equiv 1(\mod 8)$. Now, let $m=2q_1+r_1$ and $n=2q_2+r_2$ where $r_1, r_2\in\{0,1\}$.

Noticing that,

$$3^m=3^{2q_1+r_1}=(3^2)^{q_1}3^{r_1}\equiv 3^{r_1}(\mod 8)$$

and,

$$3^n=3^{2q_2+r_2}=(3^2)^{q_2}3^{r_2}\equiv 3^{r_2}(\mod 8)$$

Now, we left to check four cases: $r_1=r_2=0$, $r_1=r_2=1$, $r_1=0, \ r_2=1$ and $r_1=1, \ r_2=0$, in which after we can deduce that $3^m+3^n+1$ is not a perfect square.